# Euromillions - Does covering all the balls across a number of tickets increase chances of a (small or large) win?

Tags: probability, lotteries

So in the UK the Euromillions lottery tonight will be £167M. For those outside Europe, a Euromillions ticket consists of 5 numbers (from 1-50) and 2 lucky stars (from 1-12). Jackpot is won if the winning balls match all 5 of your numbers and both stars (5+2). Larger to small prizes are won by matching various smaller combinations of those 
e.g. 
5+1=£200k 
5+0=£16k 
4+2=£1k 
... 
2+0=£3

As a syndicate of 10, friends of mine repeatedly end up questioning their approach to choosing numbers. The syndicate buys 10 tickets, with the numbers for each of their tickets chosen individually. Inevitably, some numbers/stars are duplicated across the 10 tickets whilst other numbers don't appear on any of the tickets.

Would it make a difference to the chances of winning *something* (not necessarily the jackpot) if the syndicate made sure it covered *all* the numbers 1 to 50 and all the lucky stars 1 - 12 across the 10 tickets.

Comment: This is not a "statistics" question.  You might change the tag to "probability" or just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the chances of winning *something* will increase if you cover more numbers, since no matter what the lucky numbers are, you've gotta get them covered. However, the *expectation* of how much you win will not be improved.

Comment: Since the prizes come from pots divided by the numbers of winners of that pot, having multiple wins of the same size could reduce the value of each prize, though for the smaller prizes this is more likely than not to be lost in the rounding.  But in theory having duplicate numbers could marginally affect the expectation (and if all ten tickets are completely identical then significantly so in calculating the value of a big win)